# No such file or directory error in service

Tags: ruby, file, daemon

I  am a newbie to ruby and got stuck into one of the issues with the windows service I created (code is below). When the service runs, I get an error in test log that there is notsuch file or directory and it does not find any path to the logs with name `QaTaTestExe.log.xml`. This is the error I see in file.

> ***Daemon failure 2013-07-28 16:29:28 -0400 err=No such file or directory

However when I tried the code (which is after while running? ) in separate class it works. Am I missing anything in my configuration since the error is regarding Daemon?

```
LOG_FILE = 'C:\\test.log'

require "rubygems"
begin
  require 'win32/daemon'
  include Win32

  class Daemon
    def service_main
      while running?
        testresultpath = "Z:/Windows 2008 R2 - Exchange 2010 - Search"
        file_path s =[]
        Find.find(testresultpath) do |path|
          file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\QaTaTestExe.log.xml$/
          File.open("c:\\test.log", "a"){ |f| f.puts(path)} 
        end
        sleep 30
        File.open("c:\\test.log", "a"){ |f| f.puts "Service is running #{Time.now}" }
      end
    end
    def service_stop
      File.open("c:\\test.log", "a"){ |f| f.puts "***Service stopped #{Time.now}" }
      exit!
    end
  end
  Daemon.mainloop
rescue Exception => err
  File.open(LOG_FILE,'a+'){ |f| f.puts " ***Daemon failure #{Time.now} err=#{err} " }
  raise
end
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that Z: is mapped when the code is run as a daemon?

Comment: What is the exact line the error is happening on?